# Multiple operations in a List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Say I do something like this:

```
vList=[1236745404]
fList=[ "<td>{}</td>".format ]
[ f(x) for f, x in zip(fList, vList) ]
```

But now I want to convert the integer into a time string by feeding it into a multiple process stream.

Pseudocode:

```
fList=[ "<td>{}</td>".format(time.strftime("%a %H&#58;%M %d %b %y", time.localtime())) ]
[ f(x) for f, x in zip(fList, vList) ]
```

And what I want to see is:

```
['<td>Tue 22&#58;23 10 Mar 09</td>']
```

Is the List Comprehension variable input limited to one operation, or can the output be passed downstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two cases are quite different; in the first you have a callable (`str.format`) in the second you built a complete string.

You'd need to create a callable for the second option too; in this case a lambda would work:

```
fList=[lambda t: "<td>{}</td>".format(time.strftime("%a %H&#58;%M %d %b %y", time.localtime(t)))]
```

This is now a list with one callable, a `lambda` that accepts one argument `t`, and returns the result of the full expression where `t` is passed to `time.localtime()` then formatted using `time.strftime` then passed to `str.format()`.

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> vList=[1236745404]
>>> fList=[lambda t: "<td>{}</td>".format(time.strftime("%a %H&#58;%M %d %b %y", time.localtime(t)))]
>>> [f(x) for f, x in zip(fList, vList)]
['<td>Wed 05&#58;23 11 Mar 09</td>']
```